# Arduino stepper motor issues

Tags: button, arduino, stepper

So I am not the greatest at Arduino but I am learning. I am trying to control 2 Nema 17 stepper motors using 2 identical tb6600 drivers. They are supposed to be controlled by 6 separate buttons. For simplicity, 4 of these buttons are supposed to call a forward loop. The other 2 have other another function of spinning the second motor. When I flash this and plug everything in the 1st stepper just spins constantly. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#define STEPPIN1 13
#define STEPPIN2 10
#define DIRPIN1 12
#define DIRPIN2 9
#define ENAPIN1 11
#define ENAPIN2 8
int Button = 4;
int Button2 = 5;
int Button3 = 6;
int Button4 = 7;
int Button5 = 3;
int Button6 = 2;
int button_cond1;
int button_cond2;
int button_cond3;
int button_cond4;
int button_cond5;
int button_cond6;
int stepCount = 0;
int steps;
int j; 
int i;
void forward(int steps){
  int i;
  digitalWrite(ENAPIN1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(DIRPIN1,HIGH);
  for(i=0;i<steps;i++){
    digitalWrite(STEPPIN1, !digitalRead(STEPPIN1));
    delay(1);
  }
  digitalWrite(ENAPIN2,HIGH);
  }
  void forward2(int steps){
  int i;
  digitalWrite(ENAPIN2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(DIRPIN2,HIGH);
  for(i=0;i<steps;i++){
    digitalWrite(STEPPIN2, !digitalRead(STEPPIN2));
    delay(1);
  }
  digitalWrite(ENAPIN2,HIGH);//disable steppers
  }
//  void forwardLoop(int loops){
//    for(int i=0 ; i < loops ; i++){
//        forward(1);
//        delay(1);
//    }}
void setup() {
  pinMode(STEPPIN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(STEPPIN2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(DIRPIN1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(DIRPIN2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(ENAPIN1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(ENAPIN2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(Button, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(Button2, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(Button3, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(Button4, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(Button5, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(Button6, INPUT_PULLUP);

}

void loop() {
     button_cond1 = digitalRead(Button);
    button_cond2 = digitalRead(Button2);
    button_cond3 = digitalRead(Button3);
    button_cond4 = digitalRead(Button4);
    button_cond5 = digitalRead(Button5);
    button_cond6 = digitalRead(Button6);

    if (button_cond1 == HIGH) forwardLoop(1);
    else if (button_cond2 == HIGH) forwardLoop(1);
    else if (button_cond3 == HIGH) forwardLoop(1);
    else if (button_cond4 == HIGH) forwardLoop(1);
    else if (button_cond5 == HIGH) forward2(1);
    else if (button_cond6 == HIGH) forward2(1);
}
void forwardLoop(int loops){
    for(int j=0 ; j < loops ; j++){
        forward(1);
        delay(10);
    }}


        
//void Load(int loadSteps){
//  int i;
//  digitalWrite(ENAPIN1,LOW);
//  digitalWrite(DIRPIN1,HIGH);
//  for(i=0;i<loadSteps;i++){
//    digitalWrite(STEPPIN1, !digitalRead(STEPPIN1));
//    delay(1);}
//}



//void reverse (int steps){
//  int i; 
//  digitalWrite(ENAPIN1,LOW);
//  digitalWrite(DIRPIN1,LOW);
//  for(i=0;i<steps;i++){
//    digitalWrite(STEPPIN1, !digitalRead(STEPPIN1));
//    delay(1);
//  }
//  digitalWrite(ENAPIN1,HIGH);//disable steppers
//  }

  

//void reverse2 (int steps){
//  int i; 
//  digitalWrite(ENAPIN2,LOW);
//  digitalWrite(DIRPIN2,LOW);
//  for(i=0;i<steps;i++){
//    digitalWrite(STEPPIN2, !digitalRead(STEPPIN2));
//    delay(1);
//  }
//  digitalWrite(ENAPIN2,HIGH);//disable steppers
//  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, I would expect the motor to spin unless you pressed buttons 1-4 simultaneously. You have each button pin configured with the internal pullup, that implies that the normal state of the pin is HIGH. When you press the button, it connects that pin to ground which makes the state LOW until the button is released.

Try changing your code as follows:

```
if (button_cond1 == LOW) forwardLoop(1);
    else if (button_cond2 == LOW) forwardLoop(1);
    else if (button_cond3 == LOW) forwardLoop(1);
    else if (button_cond4 == LOW) forwardLoop(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried this and changing it to low made no difference other than now nothing works.

Comment: I was able to fix the code. The issue was in my wiring. The breadboard's power and ground did not stretch the entire run so i needed to insert jumper wires.... fml Thank you!